# i am searching a table that contains all instructions' full name in ISA

Tags: instruction-set

> could anyone give me a link to `the full name of the instructions in ISA`?

> for example, the full name of the `JAL` is `jump to link`. i search for google but i can't find something like a table which could include all of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here i found something, which is [Fundamentals of Computer Systems - The MIPS Instruction Set](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Emartha/courses/3827/sp16/mips-isa.pdf), and [MIPS instruction reference](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html)